# where to put scheduler inside my web app code?

Tags: flask, web-applications, apscheduler

I have a web application which first gets user authentication for an API token, then I want to run the latter part of the code every hour using the APScheduler module.  I dont want to run the whole app from the start, because the first part requires user interaction to authorise the app again, which is unnecessary after the first run because we have the token, plus i obviously cant be there to click the authorise button every hour.  WHere do i put the sched.start() part of the code?  THe error i get is RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

```
import requests
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session, url_for
from flask.json import jsonify
import os
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import atexit
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

client_id = "x"
client_secret = "x"
scope = 'read_station'
password = 'x'
#grant_type = 'authorization_code'
grant_type = 'password'
username='x'
authurl = 'https://api.netatmo.com/oauth2/authorize?'
token_url = 'https://api.netatmo.com/oauth2/token'
redirect_uri = 'x'
response_type = 'code'
code = None
payload= {'grant_type':grant_type,'client_id':client_id,'client_secret':client_secret,
'username':username,'password':password,'scope':scope}

rip={}
CITIES = {'bolzano' : 'lat_ne=46.30&lon_ne=11.23&lat_sw=46.28&lon_sw=11.14',
'florence' : 'lat_ne=43.51&lon_ne=11.21&lat_sw=43.44&lon_sw=11.02',
'manchester' : 'lat_ne=53.35&lon_ne=-2.0011.21&lat_sw=53.21&lon_sw=-2.36',
}
dicty = {}
def dooby(CITIES, Header):
    for city in CITIES.keys():
        i = requests.get('https://api.netatmo.com/api/getpublicdata?'+CITIES[city]+'&filter=false', headers = Header).json()
        dicty[str(city)]=i
    return dicty

@app.route('/')
def auth():
    redirect_uri = url_for('.redir', _external = True)
    oauth = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri = redirect_uri,
                          scope = scope)
    authorization_url, state = oauth.authorization_url(authurl)
    session['oauth_state'] = state
    return redirect(authorization_url)

@app.route('/redir', methods = ["GET","POST"])
def redir():
    code = request.args.get('code')
    payload['code']=code
    rip = requests.post(token_url, data=payload)
    rs = rip.content.decode()
    response = json.loads(rs)
    session['oauth_token'] = response['access_token']
    session['expiry'] = response['expires_in']
    session['refresh_token'] = response['refresh_token']

    return redirect(url_for('.profile'))

@app.route('/profile', methods = ["GET","POST"])

def profile():
    Header = {'Authorization':'Bearer '+session['oauth_token']}
    def repeat():
        return dooby(CITIES, Header)
    i = repeat()
    job = json.dumps(i)
    dt = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d %H_%M_%S")
    f = open(r'C:\Users\freak\OneDrive\Documents\UHIpaper\{}.json'.format(dt),"w")
    f.write(job)
    f.close()
    sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
    sched.add_job(func = profile,trigger='interval',minutes=2)
    sched.start()
    return jsonify(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ['DEBUG'] = "1"
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = "1"
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Hi - I am doing a similar task to yourself i.e. onetime login followed by scheduled API calls. I was just if you managed to get the scheduler to function?

Comment: I think I put the sched.start() in the final if_name_ part

    os.environ['DEBUG'] = "1"
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = "1"
    sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True,job_defaults={'misfire_grace_time': 45*60})
    sched.add_job(func = redir,trigger='cron',minute='0')
    sched.start()
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
    app.run(debug=True)

Answer (score 1):

calling `jsonify` in your `profile()` func is causing the out of context error because you're calling a Flask function without the Flask app context.

[Refer to this answer on how to add context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889082/apscheduler-running-jobs-concurrently-in-flask/61893632#61893632) or do not use `jsonify` in your `profile()` func but standard json lib instead.